# CordovaLib:processDebugResources => com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, aapt

I encounter an issue while build my cordova app :

`CordovaLib:processDebugResources => com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt`

- $ cordova -v
  7.1.0
- $ cordova platform ls
  Installed platforms:
  android 6.3.0
- $ ls /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/
  23.0.2

I've tried different things :

- ./gradlew clean build +
  ./gradlew --refresh-dependencies
  but nothing
- sudo apt-get install -y lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
  sudo apt-get install -y lib32ncurses5 lib32gomp1 lib32z1-dev
  but nothing
- change buildToolVersion and targetSdkVersion in node_modules/cordova-android/spec/fixtures/android_studio_project/app/build.gradle 
  but nothing

Any idea to solve this issue ?

Comment: I've updated android build tools to 26.0.2 and it's done !

Comment: Can you tell me literally what you did to resolve this? I don't understand your comment and I have the same problem.

Comment: Adding `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="24" />` in `config.xml` fixed the issue for me.